# Special characters are not encoded on Amazon RDS (PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, utf-8

I can not see Turkish special characters on Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database. My development database displays characters properly.

When I connect to RDS instance via pgAdmin, I see  ■aja²a³a­a@test.com instead of şajaıaüağaç@test.com.

My server encoding and collate are UTF8 and en_US.UTF-8, respectively.

In database.yml file I set encoding to utf8.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
```

There isn't any problem on my development database which is also PostgreSQL.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can remember, AWS RDS creates databases in `latin1` encoding by default. Make sure your DB's and created tables' encoding is set to `utf-8`.

Comment: When I check my client encoding with `SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;` result is **WIN1254** which is tukish character set. And when I check server encoding with `SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;` result is **UTF8**. But when I fetch data with SELECT comand it doesn't show turkish special characters properly.

Comment: I'd stick to utf8 everywhere.

Comment: I solved it. The encoding problem occurs only on pgAdmin. When I retrieve data from database Turkish characters appear correctly.